# Xcode StackView with UIImageView incorrect spacing

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, stackview

[My Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI1R5.png)

[When it runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDqNp.png)

Do u see the image that is down at the bottom? When I design it in storyboard, image with all above stuff is in a stackview with spacing of 8. Why the image is spaced from textfield too far away?

Do u guys know why?
Thanks

Comment: I think you should describe what did you do at storyboard.

Comment: Can u check, I have just added it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have constrained the stack view to the bottom of its super view.

Remove the constraint at the bottom and it should allow the stack view to lay out its views properly.

Comment: No, it does not. I only constrained it to the top, left and right. Is there anything else

Comment: @QuangDinhLuong you need to add more details to your question. Maybe a screenshot of the storyboard.